# PHP-FPM - "IntlException thrown"

Tags: php, openbsd

I have correctly installed php-8.1.23, php-fpm and php-intl-8.1.23 on OpenBSD 7.3

When I create a file locally with the following code and run it with PHP

```php
$example_var = new Collate('en_US');
```

it doesn't show any error, but when I write it inside index.php file served by a web server that does a fastcgi pass to php_fpm, it raises the following error.

```
023/09/08 19:48:58 [error] 83128#0: *73 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Default exception handler: Exception - Constructor failed Debug:
Error code: generalexceptionmessage
* line 75 of /lib/classes/collator.php: IntlException thrown
* line 75 of /lib/classes/collator.php: call to Collator->__construct()
* line 188 of /lib/classes/collator.php: call to core_collator::ensure_collator_available()
* line 263 of /lib/classes/collator.php: call to core_collator::asort()
* line 303 of /lib/classes/event/manager.php: call to core_collator::asort_objects_by_property()
* line 234 of /lib/classes/event/manager.php: call to core\event\manager::order_all_observers()
* line 103 of /lib/classes/event/manager.php: call to core\event\manager::init_all_observers()
* line 75 of /lib/classes/event/manager.php: call to core\event\manager::process_buffers()
* line 795 of /lib/classes/event/base.php: call to core\event\manager::dispatch()
* line 3670 of /course/lib.php: call to core\event\base->trigger()
* line 99 of /index.php: call to course_view()" while reading response header from upstream, client: <address>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host:
```